Balls bounce when they approach negative voltage
I am working on designing a simulation of a physical experiment, which includes a cathode and an anode. Negative electrons are emitted from the negative cathode and fall on the positive anode. However, when we make the cathode positive and the anode negative, the electrons are emitted from the positive cathode, but they repel the negative anode and return to the cathode on the same path. Knowing that as the value of the negative electrical potential difference of the anode increases with the slider, the repulsion increases.
The problem is that the electrons are emitted from the positive cathode, but they form a vertical row in the repulsion region and cannot return to the cathode.
enter code here
// Inside the onTimer function
function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
 // Move all electrons
 for (var i:int = 0; i < electrons.length; i++) {
   var myElectron:MovieClip = electrons[i];

  // Check the switch state
  if (switchState == 1) { // If the switch is on the left
  // Move the electron away from the cathode (towards the anode)
  if (myElectron.x < anodeX - 10) {
    myElectron.x += myElectron.speed; 
  }

  // Check the repulsion distance 
  var repulsionDistance:Number = 10 + voltageValue * 2;
  if (myElectron.x >= anodeX - repulsionDistance) { 
    // Move the electron towards the cathode on the same path
    myElectron.x -= myElectron.speed;
  
    // Move the electron towards the anode
    myElectron.x += myElectron.speed; 
  }

  // When myElectron reaches the cathode, remove it
  if (myElectron.x <= cathodeX) {
    // Remove myElectron from the stage
    removeChild(myElectron);
    // Remove myElectron from the electrons array
    electrons.splice(i, 1);
  }


  } else if (switchState == 0) { // If the switch is on the right
  // Move myElectron towards the anode
  myElectron.x += myElectron.speed; 
  // When myElectron reaches the anode, remove it
  if (myElectron.x >= anodeX) {
    // Remove myElectron from the stage
    removeChild(myElectron);
    // Remove myElectron from the electrons array
    electrons.splice(i, 1);
  }
  } 
  // Adjust the repulsion distance
  if (switchState == 1) { // If the switch is on the left
    // Adjust the repulsion distance based on the voltage
   } 
  }
  // Create a new electron every `electronSpacing` frame if the light is on
   if (light_on && frameCount % electronSpacing == 0) {
  // Calculate the number of new electrons based on the slider position
  var newElectrons:int = Math.round(slider.x / alpha_mc.line_mc.width * 2); // You can change 
 `10` to adjust the maximum number of electrons

  // Do not create electrons if the color is red or yellow
  if (lastColor == red_color || lastColor == yellow_color) {
    newElectrons = 0; // Do not create any electrons 
 } else {
    // Create a number of new electrons
    for (var i:int = 0; i < newElectrons; i++) {
      // Create a new electron with a random speed
      // Get the electron speed from lastColor
      var speed:Number = 0.4; // Default
      if (lastColor == green_color) {
          speed = 0.4;
      } else if (lastColor == blue_color) {
          speed = 0.6;
      } else if (lastColor == purple_color) {
          speed = 1;
      }
      speed += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.6;  // Random speed between 1 and 1.5
      createElectron(speed); 
    }
    }
  }
  frameCount++;
 }


There is an block in your code that does myElectron.x -= myElectron.speed; first but then myElectron.x += myElectron.speed; and that does not change x as the result and probably the reason the vertical line is formed.
